# Count duplicate values in PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

my problem is, i have this script

```
foreach ($arr1 as $k => $val) {
    if (in_array($val, $arr2)) {
        echo 'Obsazeno <br>';
    } else {
        echo $val . "<BR>";
    }
}
```

Where $arr1 is generated array of days and $arr2 is array from mysql results. Actually it works fine. If one of days from $arr1 is in database, it will echo "Obsazeno" instead of day value.

But i need small upgrade. Script check if $val is in $arr2 and i need small counting contidion that will do this:

If **$val** is in **$arr2** once - it will echo $val.

If **$val** is in **$arr2** twice - it will echo $val.

But if **$val** is in **$arr2** thrice - it will echo "Obsazeno".

I hope you understand my question.
I quest, it is possible by array_count_values. I try it by myself but no success.

Comment: Are you sure that in `$val` are the same values? No extra white spacing, etc.? It should work (there is no condition to value count and `in_array` returns `true` in each loop.

Comment: *I try it by myself but no success.* --- Then show us what you got so far!

Comment: Yeah, im sure. And you are right, it works but only for one same result. I need that if $val is in $arr2 only once, it is ok and script echo $val. If $val is in $arr2 twice or more (default 3) now it will echo "Obsazeno".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with [array_count_values](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.array-count-values.php).

```
$values = array_count_values($arr2);
foreach ($arr1 as $k => $val) {
    if (array_key_exists($val, $values) && $values[$val] >= 3) {
        echo 'Obsazeno <br>';
    } else {
        echo $val . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: This would raise a warning if $val isn't in $values.

Comment: It will not, cause array_key_exists will check this and the second condition gets only checked if first condition is true...

Comment: instead your "OR" between the conditions will cause a warning

Comment: this works perfectly! Thank you and thank to other guys for help

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$i=0;
foreach($arr1 as $k=>$val) {
 if(in_array($val,$arr2)) {
   $i++;
   if($i == 3) {
     echo 'Obsazeno <br>';
   }
   else {
      echo $val."<BR>";
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array();
foreach($arr1 as $k=>$val)
{
    if(!array_key_exists($val,$data)){
        $data[$val] = 0;
    }
    if(in_array($val,$arr2))
    {
        $data[$val]++;
        if($data[$val]==3){
            echo 'Obsazeno <br>';
        }else{
            echo $val."<BR>";
        }
    }
     else
    {
        echo $val."<BR>";
    }

}
```